# How do I do a sum of contents in an adjacent cell equal a set value

Tags: excel, windows-7, excel-formula

What formula would I use to do a sum of the contents of a range of cells, provided that the contents of an adjacent cell equal another cell.

The example I could give is, if I have a set of invoices which quote a purchase order, I want to see the sum of the invoices for that given purchase order, I have included a link to an excel spreadsheet where I have tried two different formulas but can't seem to get to grips with what I need to do. The formulas are in Column J.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xw9aun1cblro9ix/Test.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: `=SUMIF(C2:C4;H2;B2:B4)`

Comment: That's brilliant thank you, there was a mistake in your formula, but I replaced the ";" with a "," and it worked. how do I set your answer as the answer to this?

Comment: @pnuts it doesn't seem to work, I'll read up on how to later

Comment: @pnuts I agree, annoyingly most people don't post their comments as an answer and so don't give me a chance to mark them as having answered my question

Comment: I didn't consider this question worthy of an answer, based on the [minimum criteria of reasonable prior search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sumif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better lock the references to use absolute column references like this:

put this formula in **J** and copy down:

```
=SUMIF($C$2:$C$4,$H2,$B$2:$B$4)
```

by add the **$** sign to the column refs.